# PowerMock throwing class not found exception in test class

Tags: java, playframework, mockito

I am using Play 2.6.13 and mockito-all 2.10.19 and using sbt for building.
While executing sbt test, i am getting the below exception in test calsses:

initializationError failed: org.powermock.reflect.exceptions.FieldNotFoundException: Field 'fTestClass' was not found in class org.junit.internal.runners.MethodValidator.,

I am using the mockito by configuring in sbt as below: 
"org.mockito" % "mockito-all" % "1.10.19" % "test"

Any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be known issue: https://github.com/powermock/powermock/issues/551

According to link I provided, they renamed **fTestClass** to simply **testClass** in JUnit 4.12, so I suppose you have to use more recent PowerMock lib version.

Comment: Hi Potatojesz, I was using mockito-all 1.10.19 with Play 2.3 there was no issue. Once I upgraded to Play 2.6 then i started seeing the issue. Looks like play 2.6 is using JUnit 4.x where the class name is different. And i am not seeing any latest version of mockito-all. Are you suggesting to use powermock instead of mockito-all. Also the guthub link did not work

Comment: Oh sorry, please try now - link should work. I propse you find out which powermock version is your mockito-all using, check first if issue from the link is the one you are facing